# MySql - java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (React Native, Android)

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, react-native, jdbc

I'm developing a native module for a React Native app. In the module, I'm trying to have a JDBC connection. I've also loaded the mysql-connector-java-8.0.11 connector using android studio but I'm getting the above-mentioned error.

I've added the jar file as a module using the android studio.

The following is my code:

```
package com.myproject.helloworld;

import android.widget.Toast;


import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class MyModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  private static final String DURATION_SHORT_KEY = "SHORT";
  private static final String DURATION_LONG_KEY = "LONG";

  public MyModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "MyModule";
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
    final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
    constants.put(DURATION_SHORT_KEY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    constants.put(DURATION_LONG_KEY, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    return constants;
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void show(String message, int duration, Callback successCallback) {
      Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, duration).show();


      String str = null;

      try{
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
          Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(
          "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dgcis","root","root");

          Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select COUNTRY_NAME from exp_imp_brc limit 1;");
          while(rs.next())
          str = rs.getString(1);

          System.out.print(str);

          con.close();


      }catch(Exception e){ str = e.toString();}

      successCallback.invoke("santosh", str );

      }

}
```

this is my gradle file:

```
 apply plugin: "com.android.application"

            import com.android.build.OutputFile

            /**
             * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
             * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
             * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
             * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
             * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
             * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
             * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
             *
             * project.ext.react = [
             *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
             *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
             *
             *   // the entry file for bundle generation
             *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
             *
             *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
             *   bundleInDebug: false,
             *
             *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
             *   bundleInRelease: true,
             *
             *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
             *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
             *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
             *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
             *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
             *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
             *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
             *   // bundleInBeta: true,
             *
             *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
             *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
             *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
             *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
             *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
             *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
             *
             *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
             *   root: "../../",
             *
             *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
             *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
             *
             *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
             *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
             *
             *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
             *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
             *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
             *
             *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
             *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
             *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
             *
             *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
             *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
             *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
             *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
             *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
             *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
             *
             *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
             *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
             *
             *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
             *   extraPackagerArgs: []
             * ]
             */

            project.ext.react = [
                entryFile: "index.js"
            ]

            apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

            /**
             * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
             *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
             *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
             * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
             * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
             * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
             */
            def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

            /**
             * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
             */
            def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

            android {
                compileSdkVersion 23
                buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

                defaultConfig {
                    applicationId "com.myproject"
                    minSdkVersion 16
                    targetSdkVersion 22
                    versionCode 1
                    versionName "1.0"
                    ndk {
                        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
                    }

                }
                splits {
                    abi {
                        reset()
                        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
                        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
                        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
                    }
                }
                buildTypes {
                    release {
                        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                    }
                }
                // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
                applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                    variant.outputs.each { output ->
                        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
                        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
                        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                            output.versionCodeOverride =
                                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            dependencies {
                compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
                compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
                compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
                compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
                //compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11'


            }

            // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
            // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
            task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
                from configurations.compile
                into 'libs'
            }
```

Comment: You shouldn't connect from an android device to a MySQL database like this. It is unsafe and likely performs badly. Use a rest API as intermediary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could not be finding the module is your classpath. It could also be that while the project is aware of the file, the build script might not have the jar file in scope.

Add this to your gradle dependency

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.5'
```

Edit: updated the mysql connector version to 5.1.5 so it is compatible with 1.7 compiled code.

Comment: I've added this line to my gradle dependency "compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11' ", but I'm getting this error 'Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:WithDexForDebug
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes'

Comment: Can you post your gradle file as well?

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: Try using 5.1.5 as updated on the answer since it’s compiled with 1.7 and ships not throw the exception.

Comment: If so, I should once again import the connector, right?

Comment: well gradle sync will do that, so other than syncing gradle in android studio or running gradle build, you should not have to manually do anything else. you may want to remove the jar file you added for the 8.0.11 though to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I'm now able to connect with the db

Comment: Good to hear. Please mark the answer if it resolves your issue

Comment: 5.1.5 is ancient (10 years old). The latest 5.1.x is 5.1.46. But really, you shouldn't connect from an android device to a MySQL database like this. Use a rest API as intermediary.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to mention that I've used 5.1.44 instead of 5.1.5 as it was giving some 255 encoding error, and I'm developing this app just as a demonstration which is why I'm connecting to the DB directly.